# Inserting a document and reading it in same transaction in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Below is the code snippet I am using for one of the functionality

```
declare function local:matchCounts($Id as xs:string, $status as xs:string) as xs:int {
  xdmp:estimate(cts:search(/count, cts:and-query((
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("count"), xs:QName("Id"), $Id, "exact"),
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"), xs:QName("MatchStatus"), $status, "exact")
  )), "unfiltered"))
};

declare function local:saveCountsMatchC($Id as xs:string) {
  let $evenCount := local:matchCounts($Id, "even")
  let $oddCount := local:matchCounts($Id, "odd")
  return ($evenCount, $oddCount)
};

declare function local:matchingProcess($Id as xs:string) {
let $total-records := 1000
let $batch-size := 50
let $pagination := 0
let $bs := 
   for $records in 1 to fn:ceiling($total-records  div $batch-size )
   let $start := fn:sum($pagination + 1)
   let $end := fn:sum($batch-size + $pagination)
   let $_ := xdmp:set($pagination, $end)
   return
    xdmp:spawn-function
    (
    function() {
     for $each at $pos in ($start to $end)
     let $id := sem:uuid-string()
     let $xml := if(($pos mod 2) eq 0) then <count Id='{$Id}'><child MatchStatus='even'></child></count> 
                 else <count Id='{$Id}'><child MatchStatus='odd'></child></count>
     return xdmp:document-insert(concat("/", $id, ".xml"), $xml)
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><result>{fn:true()}</result><commit>auto</commit><update>true</update></options>
    )
let $_ := $bs
return local:saveCountsMatchC($Id)
};

local:matchingProcess("1")
```

The requirement over here is to iterate 1000 documents using batch size of 50, so basically I am using spawn function to create 20 batches of size 50  which inserts 1000 documents in my database.
Once those documents are inserted, I need to read those documents in same transaction. Here 500 documents have MatchStatus='odd' and 500 documents have MatchStatus='even'
The query should return (500,500) as output; Instead it returns (0,0)

I am using `<result>{fn:true()}</results>` option so that my next statement waits for all spawn task to be completed, but its not happeneing.

Can anybody help me with the requirement?

Note: Need to insert 1000 documents and then read them in same function call only

Comment: Questions like these always make me wonder about the why of trying to do it this way. It might be wise to take a step back, and ask yourself if you really need to do all this in the same call. Doing many updates in a single call doesn't scale, and attempts to read the result as well doesn't make it simpler..

Answer (score 1):

Your code that executes the spawns does not perform updates itself, so will run in so-called query mode. In query mode only updates from before the start of the code are visible.

You could try running in update mode ([`declare option xdmp:transaction-mode "update";`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-transaction-mode)), but usually it is easier to just spawn or eval the counting/reading of your updates as well. E.g. wrap the `xdmp:estimate` in an `xdmp:spawn-function` with result `true` as well.

HTH!